# Как убрать все слова в строке кроме 3 последних?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне надо действие, которое будет убирать все слова в строке, кроме 3 последних.
(Число строк которые надо убрать не определённые)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def f(string, number):
    return ' '.join(string.split(' ')[-number:])
```

Comment: А можно что-бы не убирался пробел? Или что-бы теперь убиларось 'до'

Comment: @kotivas Ой ошибся, так работает?

Comment: @kotivas Примите ответ если он вам помог .

Comment: @kotivas Рекомендую разобраться как это работает. Чтобы сами могли похожую задачу решить.

Comment: Кстати, если не указывать аргумент у split, то сработает и на произвольном числе пробелов, табуляции, переводе строки и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf угу ...

Answer (score 3):

```py
inp1 = 'Привет, в этой строке есть слова, я хочу получить 3 последних'
inp2 = 'Мало слов'

'''
input:
    inp<str> - строка на входе
    count<int> - Количество последних строк 
return:
    str - строка с тремя последними словами
'''
def a(inp, count):
    # Для начала разбиваем строку по пробельному символу
    buff = inp.split(" ")

    # Выполним выборку слов только если слов в строке больше чем нам надо
    # В противном случае буфер не изменится и мы вернем столько слов, сколько есть
    if len(buff) > count:
        # Получм 3 последних элемента
        # buff[-3:] говорит о том, что мы получаем 3 элемента с конца
        buff = buff[-count:]

    # Оьъеденим полученные элементы массива
    # Если у строки вызвать метод join он возьмет нашу строку как сепаратор
    buff = ' '.join(buff)
    return buff

print(a(inp1, 3))
print(a(inp2, 3))
```

Comment: В принципе это тоже самое что у меня, тока степ бай степ. для начинающих норм

Comment: проверка `if len(buff) > count` является излишней. Срез `buf[-count:]` нормально отработает даже если в `buf` меньше чем `count` элементов

Comment: @Victor VosMottor thanks Monica Ну учитывая такой вопрос, автор и есть начинающий, мне кажется, что лучше показывать наглядно "степ бай степ", чтобы он не просто CTRL+C, CTRL+V а хотя бы понимал, что там происходит

Comment: @Mamba Yeah.....

Answer (score 0):

1. В задаче не сказано, что слова обязательно должны быть разделены пробелом, а следовательно они могут быть разделены табуляцией `\t` либо переносом строки `\n`, в том числе в конце строки
2. В задаче сказано "убрать все слова", следовательно разделители между словами должны остаться неизменными

Отсюда выходит что приведенные ответы "не совсем корректны"

Возможно мой вариант не самый оптимальный, но он отражает смысл задачи

```
string_ = '''
word1 word2 word3
word4\tword5
'''

def qwe(string_, sep = ' \n\t'):
    count=0
    for s in reversed(string_.rstrip()):
        if count == 3: break
        elif s in sep: count += 1
        yield s

last3 = ''.join(reversed(list(qwe(string_)))).lstrip()
print(last3)
```

out:

```
word3
word4   word5
```

В выводе сохранены изначальные разделители слов, такие как `\n` и `\t`

Comment: `а следовательно они могут быть разделены табуляцией \t либо переносом строки \n` - откуда это следует? Почему вы решили, что разделителями слов могут быть только пробелы, табуляции и символ перевода строки? ;)

Comment: ну может и не только (`могут быть`), я к тому, что завязыватся только на пробел нельзя

Comment: если бы было сказано получить 3 последних слова, списком например - это одно, но сказано убрать из строки - т.е. сохранить ее оригинальный вид

Answer (score -1):

```
str_s = str.split(" ")
array = []
array.append(str_s[-1])
array.append(str_s[-2])
array.append(str_s[-3])
str_ = array[0] + ' ' + array[1] + ' ' + array[2]
```

Comment: по моему очень криво

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica  Это работает.

Comment: Ну и что???????

Comment: Вы решили привести пример того, как __не надо__ кодировать на Python? ;)

Comment: Нет правда, это ж не джава...

Comment: @MaxU Ого, да там сверху еще более е-едреный код...

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]